# laravel eloquent: Eloquent relation needs to return something when there is no data instead of returning null object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this relation on my product model.

```
public function productInventory(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Ecommerce\Inventory', 'product_id')->where('is_deleted', 0);
}
```

Sometimes, i may not have inserted that specific product in my inventory table. So, this relation is still in play with view but will try to get the productInventory->price which will throw an error, **cannot get price of null object**. So, I've done this now which is just a simple thing to do. But the count is 1 or greater than 1, because there are other products. So how will I be able to return only null for that specific product which has no data in the inventory table?

```
public function productInventory(){
        $has_inv = Inventory::where('product_id',$this->id)->where('is_deleted', 0)->count();        
        if($has_inv < 1){
            return null;
        }
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Ecommerce\Inventory', 'product_id')->where('is_deleted', 0);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just check `if ($productInventory->price === null)`?

Comment: yes that might work. But I have to put it in every single pages i have. I've used the relation in many different pages. so, I wanted to do something at the model relation. Thank you. If you can help me can you upvote this question?

Comment: @rakib  i've used it on the blade using standard eloquent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the method productInventory() must return the relationship. it does not matter that there is no connected Inventory for some records. This method must return the relationship, that's all... Confusing this return with the actual state of the DB ("for this specific product there is no inventory"), is a real no go, IMHO.

So, if your problem lies in the view, there you get an error when there is no inventory, a better solution would be:

Check in the view if there is an object available and only then check for the price attribute on that object.

You can check it with something like...

```
@if(is_null($productInventory)) 
 {{$productInventory->price}}
@endif
```

BTW this is an EXAMPLE of code, not actual real code. But it gives you an idea of where to solve this problem.

Because, you are solving this in the wrong place. The relationship method is NOT the place, imho.

If you use this in a lot of views, you have to optimize your VIEW structure (by using includes!), not move with problem to a diferent place in your code.

Make an include for the view code you use a lot and include is with something like:

```
@include('product_incventory_price_data')
```

**About includes in Blade**

Let's use the example for your `<head>` code in your webpages. You can add this to all individual web pages (your view files). let's look at two different views (A en B)

file: view_a.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{$page->title}}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{$page->description}}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{$page->keywords}}">
</head>
<body>
...stuff for view A
</body>
</html>
```

file: view_b.blade.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{$page->title}}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{$page->description}}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{$page->keywords}}">
</head>
<body>
...stuff for view B
</body>
</html>
```

A better solution: move all `<head>` code to a different file (in a folder like views/shared). And include that file in both A en B views.

shared/head.blade.php

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{$page->title}}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{{$page->description}}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{{$page->keywords}}">
</head>
```

view_a

```
<html>
@include('shared/head')
<body>
...stuff for view A
</body>
</html>
```

view_b

```
<html>
@include('shared/head')
<body>
...stuff for view B
</body>
</html>
```

You can do this with all kinds of pieces of view code. Also your product price information could be move to one place and used in multiple other views with the @include()...

The data you pass to the views by your controller is passed also to the include files. Don't worry about that.... :-)

[Laravel documentation about views & sub-views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#including-sub-views)

Comment: I was about to upvote this answer. But the views are many and big. So, you wanted me to use include.. How should I use that include can you elaborate a little, it can be used in the blade right. for that i have to send my Product instance.

Comment: I will add an exmaple